# (Rank * Suit) option list to (Rank * Suit) list option

Tags: f#

What would be the most succinct way to go from

```
(Rank * Suit) option list -> (Rank * Suit) list option
```

The reason is, I'm reading from the command line two card hands `"4S 4H 4D 4C AS; JS KD QC 10H 2C"`, so I parse each part of a hand, then return the full hand which obviously could fail.

So if any of the first set of `(Rank * Suit)` are `None` then that would shortcircuit and return `None` (of `(Rank * Suit) list`)

If they are all `Some` (of (Rank * Suit) option) then it would return `Some` (of `(Rank * Suit) list`)

So I got as far as

```ml
type Rank = One | Two | Three
type Suit = Spades | Hearts

type Card = Rank * Suit

[ Some (One, Spades); Some (Two, Hearts); None ] 
  |> List.map (fun card -> Option.map (fun actualCard -> ) )
```

And my brain kinda melted... I kinda feel like I need some kind of Option.collect method... or Option.reduce something...

---

### Edit

That last statement got me thinking:

```ml
  cards
  |> Seq.map parseCard
  |> Seq.fold (fun agg elem -> 
                  match agg with
                  | Some l -> 
                      match elem with
                      | Some card -> Some ( l @ [ card ] )
                      | None -> None
                  | None -> None ) (Some [])
```

There must be a more succinct way?

---

#### Edit 2

is this it?

```ml
cards
  |> Seq.map parseCard
  |> Seq.fold (fun agg elem -> 
                  agg |> Option.bind ( fun l -> 
                    elem |> Option.map ( fun card ->
                      l @ [ card ]
                    )
                  )) (Some [])
```

Comment: @TeaDrivenDev I've updated my question with a possible answer... is there no function that does that `bind >> map` in one go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function you're looking for is normally called  `sequence` and it's part of a more generic abstraction called [Traversable](http://fsprojects.github.io/FSharpPlus/abstraction-traversable.html).

For lists and options you can code it like this:

```
let sequence t = List.foldBack (Option.map2 (fun x y -> x::y)) t (Some [])
```

usage

```
sequence [ Some (One, Spades); Some (Two, Hearts) ]
// val it : (Rank * Suit) list option = Some [(One, Spades); (Two, Hearts)]

sequence [ Some (One, Spades); Some (Two, Hearts); None ]
// val it : (Rank * Suit) list option = None
```

Comment: just out of curiosity, why foldBack instead of fold?

Comment: You can also use `fold` but then you can't do the cons operation on lists, you would have to do it like this `let sequence t = List.fold (Option.map2 (fun x y -> x@[y])) (Some []) t` which is less natural for lists.

Comment: Sorry I got it now, yeah the `::` would mean you have to build the list up backwards... nice, that is an interesting nuance...

Answer (score 3):

What about something super simple and easy to understand:

```
let parseHand cards =
    let maybeCards = cards |> List.map parseCard
    if maybeCards |> List.contains None
    then None
    else Some (maybeCards |> List.choose id)
```

Comment: Yeah I love the simplicity of this pretty awesome answer!